# closing a silverlight window on button click

Tags: silverlight, xaml

There are Ok and Cancel buttons in a silverlight window.

When clicking cancel button on that window how can I close the window?

Answer (score 0):

If the SilverLight application is hosted in a WebBrowser then you can redirect the browser to another page:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("../Login/Login.aspx", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use next statement:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("close");
```